# Decoding x-www-form-urlencoded to array

Tags: php, arrays, rest, parsing, put

I'm trying to transform PUT request params to a key=>value array in my server.

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $data);
```

This way I get a "dirt" array like this:

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "birth_date"

1995-01-03
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"

15
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXX--

)
```

How can I extrapolate just the two key=>values without manually parsing the content...?

Comment: that PUT request was definitely constructed improperly

Answer (score 0):

The request's body params were encoded in `multipart/form-data` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The *x-www-form-urlencoded* version would look like this:

```
birth_date=1995-01-03&age=15
```

Parsing *multipart/form-data* is a little bit more advanced. As far as I know there is no built-in function in PHP to do that.
But there are third party libraries that you may use: https://github.com/h4cc/multipart

If you are able to chenge the way the request is encoded it would be much easier and less error prone to change the encoding to *x-www-form-urlencoded*.